# Can I use wsdl2php on a plain XSD document?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xsd2code, wsdl2php

I'm trying to generate classes for the [OVF xsd](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/ovf). I've found a bunch of incomplete/broken projects. I was thinking that [wsdl2php](http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/) might work, but it looks like it expects a WSDLdocument and not an XSD.

Is there a way to make it generate the classes for the XSD?

Comment: Reason for not being a duplicate: the question is specifically can I generate classes from an XSD using wsdl2php. That question points to a bunch of dead ends.